# Passsing an image from one view to other

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiimage

I have two view controllers in my app and both views have table view in them and both table views have certain buttons in them representing some images.when i select a button from table view in view 1 then image corresponding to that button is to set on the button1 in table view in view 2.How can i do it.How can i pass image from a view to other .Please respond.

Thanks,
Christy

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329724/adding-image-to-a-button-in-other-view

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330258/accessing-a-button-of-a-table-view-from-other-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what named properties are useful for.

Let's say view 2 has this (among other things):

```
@interface ViewTwo :: UIViewController
{
    UIImage *viewTwoImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *viewTwo;

@end;
```

And then

```
@implementation ViewTwo

@synthesize viewTwoImage;

-(void)dealloc
{
    [viewTwoImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Then elsewhere (ie wherever you're creating your instance of this view controller) you can say:

```
ViewTwo *myViewTwo = [[ViewTwo alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewTwo" bundle:nil];
myViewTwo.viewTwoImage = myUIImageFromThisController;
```

And you've now initialized your view two instance with a pointer to that same UIImage in its `.viewTwoImage` property. ViewTwo can then use that image for whatever it's useful for, in its `-(void)viewDidLoad` method.